# Cloud based password management

Tags: php, html, encryption

I am currently working on an ICT project which is basically a password management system.

It'll allow users to:

1. Input a username and password which they would like to store .
2. Encrypts that to the database.
3. I would like to make a file explorer type of navigation where they can view the passwords they save, in a separate tab of the same web-app.

Obviously these passwords need to be encrypted, only problem is - as far as I understood from some research - that hashing is not the way to go as it is only one way.

I saw something about Symmetric encryption using a key and that seems to be the way to go. Therefore, my question is :

**How would I implement this idea** whereby during registration the user can specify a number (which would be their key for encryption), and beable to store that so that when a user wishes to browse one of their passwords, they can enter the key and get the plain-text password.

The current login system I'm using is just one I found from a [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69771-creating-a-simple-yet-secured-loginregistration-with-php5/)

I'm working on improving that one and integrating with the rest of the website/webapp. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Why limit the encryption key to a number?

Comment: I'm not limiting anything, I was only really giving an example. I'm a bit new to this sort of stuff and it was the best way I could phrase it. I'm just asking about the method to even implement this idea.